# Comparing Nullable Datetime got error Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
public static class ClientActivityUtilities
{
    private static SalesforceEntities sf = new SalesforceEntities();  //DBContext
    private static DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    public static void method1()
    {
        List<TaskResult> taskResult = new List<TaskResult>();
        var Advisors=sf.Accounts.Where(b=>(b.Account_Type__c.Equals("Advisor")||b.Account_Type__c.Equals("Provider"))&&b.Monthly_Activity_Reporting__c.Equals("1")&&b.Account_Status__c.Equals("active"))
            .Select(a=>
            new{
                a.Id,
                a.Client_Territories__c,
                a.Name
            }).AsNoTracking().ToList();




        foreach (var advisor in Advisors)
        {

            int voicemail = 0;
            int conversationwithcsuite = 0;
            int conversationwithhr = 0;
            int conversationother = 0;
            int followupreminder = 0;
            int nomessageleft = 0;


            var clients = sf.Accounts.Where(b => b.Client_Territories__c.Equals(advisor.Client_Territories__c))
                .Select(a =>
                new
                {
                    a.Id
                }).AsNoTracking().ToList();

            foreach(var client in clients)
            {


                voicemail += sf.Tasks.Count(t => t.WhatId.Equals(client.Id) && t.CallType__c.Equals("Left Voicemail") && t.CreatedDate != null && (DateTime.Compare(t.CreatedDate.Value, new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month - 1, 1))>=0));
```

The last line gives me error "Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities."

I am new to c# and do you know what's wrong with this?
I think the problem is with this because after i remove this it works with no error.
    (DateTime.Compare(t.CreatedDate.Value, new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month - 1, 1))>=0)
The field CreatedDate is a nullable datetime field.
I want to set the filter to be created date greater than last month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing that line with

```
var lastMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month - 1, 1);
voicemail += sf.Tasks.Count(t => t.WhatId.Equals(client.Id) && t.CallType__c.Equals("Left Voicemail") && t.CreatedDate != null && (DateTime.Compare(t.CreatedDate.Value, lastMonth) >=0));
```